# Immediately receive message send from server(Servlet to android)

Tags: android, servlets

I want to know if it is possible to Immediately receive a message that send from server(Servlet) to the client(Andriod), and the client side can notice the message and Immediately respond to it?

Thanks for Help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,

Push notifications are you way to go..

Google offers C2DM as push notification service for android.

[Here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html) is nice tutorial for push notification

Answer (score 0):

You can.

HAVE A LOOK AT : 
http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-get-post-and-multipart-post-requests/

Answer (score 0):

Your question has no sufficient details. But I think you want to ask:
As your application is installed and run on device your server send a message.
As message is received by your device, it sends response.

Yes it is possible. As your application install and run, you should call your servlet from your onCreate or onStart method. As your server message receives you will again send the message from your device.
Snippet:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
String getURL = "http://www.yourserver/servlet";
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(getURL);
HttpResponse responseGet = client.execute(get);  
HttpEntity resEntityGet = responseGet.getEntity();  
if (resEntityGet != null) {  
  //do something with the response 
  //or call another url hit with your message
}
```

and second request on response receive is

```
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
        String postURL = "http://yourserver";
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(postURL); 
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", "your message"));
        UrlEncodedFormEntity ent = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,HTTP.UTF_8);
        post.setEntity(ent);
        HttpResponse responsePOST = client.execute(post);  
        HttpEntity resEntity = responsePOST.getEntity();  
        if (resEntity != null) {    
            Log.i("RESPONSE",EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
        }
```

--------------------------Edit---------------

You should go through [C2DM](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/). This is push notification service for Android devices and you must follow the whole procedure of [C2DM](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/).

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question. I mean the message is send from server side and is Initiative by the server like the android device receive a message from other user though the servlet